# Splitting up a JSON array into rows of four items each (while keeping everything observable)

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I get a certain data structure when I call my GET api/home API endpoint - there are two arrays: one for Books and one for Magazines.  I'd like to display the items in a grid of four items per row, but I'm not sure how to do it.  I also need to keep these items (knockout) observable - within my viewModel I have:

```
var mapping = {
        create: function(options) {
            //customize at the root level.  
            var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);

            return innerModel;
        }
    };

    var homeViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(homeData, mapping);
    //debugger;
    return homeViewModel;
```

Within my view I have:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <!-- ko foreach: books -->
        <div class="span3">
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko foreach: magazines -->
        <div class="span3">
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

But I need to have a "row-fluid" for each row, which contains four items unless it's the last row, which could contain less than four items (books or magazines).  Right now it's just a single "row-fluid" that contains everything, so the layout's all mucked up.

I'm thinking I can use the $id of the elements to figure out if I should create a new row-fluid ($id%4 == 0), however I'm not sure how to keep everything observable if I do this, or how to restructure my viewModel.  Any tips would be much appreciated!

homeData defined below:

```
 var homeData = {
        "$id": "1",
        "totalBooks": 40,
        "totalMagazines": 20,
        "books": [
            {
                "$id": "2",
                "bookId": 1,
                "title": "Test Title"                
            },
            {
                "$id": "3",
                "bookId": 2,
                "title": "Test Title"                
            },
            {
                "$id": "4",
                "bookId": 3,
                "title": "Test Title"                
            },
            {
                "$id": "5",
                "bookId": 4,
                "title": "Test Title"                
            },
            {
                "$id": "6",
                "bookId": 5,
                "title": "Test Title"                
            },
            {
                "$id": "7",
                "bookId": 6,
                "title": "Test Title"                
            },
            {
                "$id": "8",
                "bookId": 7,
                "title": "Test Title"                
            },
            {
                "$id": "9",
                "bookId": 8,
                "title": "Test Title"                
            }
        ],
        "magazines": [
            {
                "$id": "9",
                "magazineId": 1,
                "title": "test magazine 0",
            },
            {
                "$id": "10",
                "magazineId": 2,
                "title": "test magazine 0",
            },
            {
                "$id": "11",
                "magazineId": 3,
                "title": "test magazine 0",
            },
            {
                "$id": "12",
                "magazineId": 4,
                "title": "test magazine 0",
            },
            {
                "$id": "13",
                "magazineId": 5,
                "title": "test magazine 0",
            }]};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I've done for this use case is make a computed observable that is an array of arrays, first level being rows and second level being columns.

```
var groupObsArray = function(itemsPerGroup,observableArray) {
    return ko.computed(function() {
        var obsArrData = observableArray();
        var groupedItems = [];
        var aGroup = [];
        for (var i=0;i<obsArrData.length;i++)
        { 
            aGroup.push(obsArrData[i])
            if(i%itemsPerGroup === 0) {
                groupedItems.push(aGroup);
                aGroup = [];
            }
        }
        return groupedItems;
    });
}
var mapping = {
    create: function(options) {
        //customize at the root level.  
        var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);

        return innerModel;
    }
};

var homeViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(homeData, mapping);

homeViewModel.MagazineRows = groupObsArray(4,homeViewModel.magazines);
homeViewModel.BookRows = groupObsArray(4,homeViewModel.books);
```

the markup

```
<div class="readingMaterials magazines" data-bind="foreach:MagazineRows">
    <div class="row-fluid" data-bind="foreach:$data">
        <div class="span3" data-bind="text:title">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks scaryman, I'll try this out now.